# How to add next interaction after seftInterval?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a setInterval that puts a "typewriter text" on the website. After a paragraph is finished, I would like to add a next button below it. So the reader can read the part first and after click on "next" the new paragraph starts. Could you help me? Thank you.

The "start-btn" and "headline-text" become none when clicked and the text begins.

```css
startBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    document.getElementById("start-btn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("headline-text").style.display = "none";

    setInterval(function(){
        document.querySelector("#game-adventure").innerHTML = text.slice(0, index);
        index++;
    }, 50);
})
```

Comment: So when index reaches the max length, kill the interval and call code that shows the button.

Comment: ok. I think I have an idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the length of the string. When it is greater, you call code that runs it. I would use a timeout instead of an interval

```js
function typeIt(text, elem, delay, nextStep) {

  let index = 0;

  const type = () => {
    index++;

    if (index > text.length) {
      nextStep();
      return;
    }

    elem.innerHTML = text.slice(0, index);
    window.setTimeout(type, delay);

  }


  type();
}

const elem = document.querySelector("#game-adventure");
typeIt('Hello world!', elem, 100, () => { console.log('done'); });
```

```html
<div id="game-adventure"></div>
```

If you really want to use an interval, you would need to clear it.

```js
function typeIt(text, elem, delay, nextStep) {

  let index = 0;

  const type = () => {
    index++;

    if (index > text.length) {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
      nextStep();
      return;
    }

    elem.innerHTML = text.slice(0, index);

  }

   const timer = window.setInterval(type, delay);
   type();

}

const elem = document.querySelector("#game-adventure");
typeIt('Hello world!', elem, 100, () => { console.log('done'); });
```

```html
<div id="game-adventure"></div>
```